# PHP show return from python script

Tags: php, python, output, exec

I am unable to get php to show full results of my python script, only the last basic print statement is printed. What am I doing wrong here? Why is the php not showing the output from the python script?

php

```
$result = exec('python list.py');
echo $result;
```

list.py

```
import subprocess

print "start"

a = subprocess.Popen(["ls", "-a"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
a.wait()
result_str = a.stdout.read()
print result_str

print "stop"
```

the command line output for that python script is as below

```
start
...filename
...filename
...etc...etc

stop
```

The php output from executing the python script is only

> stop

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `$result` as a param into `exec()` otherwise you only get the last statement.

```
exec('python list.py', $result);
print_r($result);
```

This will get an array of output, `$result[0]` will contain `stop` and `$result[sizeof($result)-1]` will contain `stop` and everything in between will contain the rest of your program output.

Comment: This using print_r($result); shows me Start and ($result[0]) shows me S, but ($result[-1]) shows me nothing.
print_r($result[sizeof($result)-1]); shows me S

Comment: @Anthony please re-read what I wrote. It seems you're still doing `$result = exec('python list.py');` instead of `exec('python list.py', $result);`

Comment: Doing it as written exec('python list.py', $result);
print_r($result[0]); and I get the results as stated above

Comment: I've tested and confirmed that the **only** way you're getting this is if you're still doing `$result = exec('python list.py');` OR `$result = exec('python list.py', $result);`. The exact code I provided works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

**`exec`** will **always** return **the last line from the result of the command**. So, if you need to get every line of output from the command executed. Then, you need to write as below :

```
$result = exec('python list.py', $ouput);
print_r($output)
```

As per **[exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)** documentation

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

> **If the `output` argument is present, then the specified array will be
>   filled with every line of output from the command.** Trailing
>   whitespace, such as \n, is not included in this array. Note that if
>   the array already contains some elements, exec() will append to the
>   end of the array. If you do not want the function to append elements,
>   call unset() on the array before passing it to exec().